# Why is this cardinal regular?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I have the following problem in front of me.

> Show that if $\kappa$ is the least cardinal such that $2^\kappa>2^{\aleph_0},$ then $\kappa$ is regular.

I've scribbled this:

Suppose $$\kappa=\coprod_{\alpha<\lambda}X_\alpha,$$ where $\lambda<\kappa$ is a cardinal, and for each $\alpha<\lambda$ we have $|X_\alpha|<\kappa.$ Then $$\Large 2^{\aleph_0}<2^\kappa=2^{\coprod_{\alpha<\lambda}X_\alpha}=\prod_{\alpha<\lambda}2^{X_\alpha}=(\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}2^{X_\alpha})^\lambda.$$

If the last thing were equal to $2^\lambda$, I would get a contradiction, and I'd be done. But I have no idea what the last thing equals.

I also tried to write down some formulas with cofinality and suprema, but I didn't get any farther. What's the simplest way to do it? The thing above uses some nontrivial facts that I don't even understand very well.

Comment: Is this $\kappa$ not just $\aleph_1$ (under the axiom of choice)? If so, then this problem becomes much easier.

Comment: @William: No; it’s consistent with ZFC that $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}=\omega_2$, for instance, in which case $\kappa=\omega_2$.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Bukovský-Hechler theorem that, in particular, gives us that if $\tau$ is infinite, then $2^\tau=(\sup_{\rho<\tau}2^{|\rho|})^{\mathrm{cf}(\tau)}$. Apply this with $\tau=\kappa$ singular, assuming that $2^\mu=2^{\aleph_0}$ for all cardinals $\mu<\kappa$. For more on this result, see [here](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/580-cardinal-arithmetic-2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\lambda=\operatorname{cf}\kappa$, and let $\langle\alpha_\xi:\xi<\lambda\rangle$ be a cofinal sequence in $\kappa$. Then $|\alpha_\xi|<\kappa$ for each $\xi<\lambda$, so $2^{|\alpha_\xi|}\le 2^\omega$ for each $\xi<\lambda$. Thus, $\sup_{\xi<\lambda}2^{|\alpha_\xi|}=2^\omega$, and $(2^\omega)^\lambda=2^\lambda$ (since $\lambda\ge\omega$). And if $\lambda<\kappa$, then $2^\lambda\le 2^\omega<2^\kappa$.

Note that you don’t actually need equality in the last step of your displayed line: all you need for this result is that

$$\prod_{\alpha<\lambda}2^{|X_\alpha|}\le\left(\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}2^{|X_\alpha|}\right)^\lambda\;,$$

which is pretty easy to see.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand something. I think we need to get a contradiction with minimality from $\lambda<\kappa.$ But $2^\lambda\leq 2^\omega$ doesn't seem give a contradiction. I think it just means that $2^\lambda=2^\omega$ and the minimality of $\kappa$ is fine...

Comment: @Bartek: The contradiction is with the lefthand end of your long displayed formula: you have $2^\omega<2^\omega$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've been looking at this this whole time, and I still don't see what you mean. I don't understand in what relation what you said is to the formula I posted above. You say that the left-hand end of what I wrote is in contradiction with something, but I'm not sure what. The left-hand end is just $2^{\aleph_0}<2^\kappa.$ I'm extremely tired right now, so maybe I'll try to sleep a bit and look a it again. Thank you again.

Comment: @Bartek: Assume that $\langle\alpha_\xi:\xi<\lambda\rangle$ is strictly increasing, and let $X_\xi=\alpha_{\xi+1}\setminus\alpha_\xi$. Then $$2^\omega<2^\kappa=2^{\sqcup_{\xi<\lambda}|X_\xi|} \le\prod_{\xi<\lambda}2^{|X_\xi|}\le\left(\sup_{\xi<\lambda}2^{|X_\xi|}\right)^{\lambda} \le(2^\omega)^\lambda=2^\lambda=2^\omega\;,$$ so $2^\omega<2^\omega$.